# Win 7; How to stop the Explorer left navigation pane from opening it's folders when you click on drive letters?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

On my 2nd bootable backup drive (W7 freshly compiled from NTLite), when I click on a drive letter in the navigation pane, it keeps on opening folders there and the center pane. That makes it really hard ti use the left pane w/o manually condensing it back down to just the single 'Computer' entry. I have multiple drives with a total of seven partitions, I don't want to have it open both listings of the partition I'm interested in.

I realize I can click on the "-" before the drive or Computer entry too collapse the directory everytime, but that is a real pain and doesn't solve the problem.

My main bootable drive (loaded with W7 from RT7 Lite) does not have this problem.

BTW, when I use a open, save or save as dialog box, clicking on a drive letter only opens folders in the right pane (as it should).

Comment: Do you have Tools > Folder Options > General > Navigation Pane > "Show all folders" and "Automatically expand to current folder enabled"?

Comment: No, both are unchecked, I never had those checked. I did try checking them,  but it basically made things worse.